# Not able to update user profile property for user with Contribute permission

Tags: 2013, user-profile-property

I am trying to update the user profile property as by the method in this [link](http://sympmarc.com/2014/02/04/spservices-stories-20-modify-user-profile-properties-on-sharepoint-online-2013-using-spservices/). It is working for the user with permission Full Control. But it is not updating for the user with contribute permission. How can I update their own user profile property for the user with contribute permission?

Answer (score 1):

On the link you posted, did you check the note:

> You can only edit the user profile properties that are editable
>   (unlocked) on your MySite. Certain fields like department are usually
>   locked for editing as per company policy

Ensure that the below setting is checked for that property.

[image]

Comment: Yeah.. I found that and updated already but when updating the user profile property it gives me Internal Server Error 500(/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx)

Comment: Check the value that returns on loginname. The format should be `domain\user`

Comment: Yes, it returns correctly....Actually, I just made rootsite/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx after changing to site collection level rootsite/<sitecollection>/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx it works.Thanks for the help man..